# Setting Default value for drop down based on a number field.

Tags: jquery, dropdown, number

I have a simple request from my manager to make a change in the default Edit Form for a share point list.
I have a number field which allows one decimal value and a drop down field with dedicated, shared and select a value(default value) . I have a requirement to check if the number field is less than one then the drop down should be assigned   to shared without the user selecting anything from the dropdown.

I am aware of jquery so if you could help please do.
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Add a script editor web part in new/edit form and add something like below:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("input[title='numberfield']").change(function(){
if($("input[title='numberfield']").val()<=1)
{
    $("input[title='DrpNamefield']").val('Shared')
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: i figured out the way to do this but thank you for your help. in your code .val() < "1" changes should be made to make the code work, then only it is working! @deepmala

Comment: Number fields shouldn't be encoded in quotes.

Comment: i will keep that in mind !